# how can i use the result i got back from the web (json result) to either make the user move on to the next page or not

Tags: xcode, swift

The registraion after user enter the save button after filling the info needed the request return with ID for the user or (-1) , (-2)  for errors i tried if condation but isn't working like hoped , when i \print(response.result.value) the result is : Optional("\r\nhttp://*******-********-Data.org/\">\"-1\"") , what can i do

[image: Image showing code]

Comment: Is the returned data XML or JSON? If it's the former it's not needed to create JSON from XML. If it's the latter, it's not needed to create XML from JSON.

Comment: i  wrote this code in another class and call it and input the url that has the details in like this (let path =  ".............firstName=\(firstName)&lastName=\(LastName)&mobile=\(MobileNum)) and in return i get the respond as id or -1 , -2  ...     -I tried  the above method and tried to input it in var but it didn't work (let respond = jsson as String )

Comment: @vadian well i tried it    the returned data is XML as u can see

Comment: when i \print(response.result.value) the result is : Optional("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<string xmlns=\"http://*******-*******-Data.org/\">\"-1\"</string>")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the console log I guess the returned data is XML.

So creating JSON from XML is useless.

Try this

<strike>if let root = doc.root {
      let data = root.stringValue
      if data == "-1" {
        ...</strike>

**Edit**: The source text reveals that the result string is quoted so it's

```
if let root = doc.root {
  let data = root.stringValue
  if data == "\"-1\"" {
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for answering , but it didn't work do u have anything in your mind that can work ? sorry for bothering u :)

Comment: could you print `response.result.value` and add the result to your question?

Comment: Optional("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<string xmlns=\"http://*****-********-Data.org/\">\"-1\"</string>")

Comment: you are the man thanks alot worked perfectly , can u explain to me plz why this worked and not "-1" i know it have something to do with version=\"1.0\"  sorry i'm new at this

Comment: Normally a string is represented by a pair of double quotes `"-1"`. If the string itself is wrapped in quotes each quote must be escaped by a backslash `"\"-1\""` like the other escaped quotes in the XML string.

Comment: @killvak where does that `XMLDocument` class come from?